# Where is default location of Keras in Ubuntu OS

Tags: ubuntu, keras

I got an idiot question, (in Ubuntu OS) could someone tell me where is the default location of Keras? I'll need to change the configuration file.

Comment: The configuration file is ~/.keras/keras.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ubuntu os, the default location is:

```
usr/lib/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Where you can find other files `Theano`, `Tensorflow` as well. It is convenient to check the source codes and customise your own low level functions.